# How to print debug info from the Emulator?

Tags: emulation, android

I'm trying to connect to a server on my machine with an android app hosted on an emulator on my machine.  I know I'm supposed to connect to the IP "10.0.2.2" and I've set the INTERNET permission in the manifest file, but it isn't working.  That said, if I could print debug statements I can probably figure this out myself.

I'm using Log.d(...), how can I get to the text it outputs?  Or should I use something else?

Comment: Development questions are offtopic, this site is for Android use.  Your question may be migrated to StackOverflow.com.

Comment: You can also use logcat in the sdk tools folder to print output from the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the command line and type ddms

If you don't have the Android SDK in your path, go to where you installed the SDK and look for ddms in the tools directory.  Once you start ddms you can select the device and view logging in the bottom window.